# requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool

Tags: python, requests

Ошибка: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='uchim.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gdz/3-russkij-yazyk-grekov-kryuchkov-cheshko-10-11-klass/368 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
Использую для хоста pythonanywhere

````
import os
links='https://uchim.org/gdz/3-russkij-yazyk-grekov-kryuchkov-cheshko-10-11-klass/'
for_links='https://uchim.org'
ex=str(input())
responce = requests.get(links + ex).text
res1 = responce[responce.find('src="/gdz-files/') + 5:responce.find('.gif"') + 4]
link = (for_links + res1)
r = requests.get(link,proxies={"https": "https://95.153.67.17:8080"})
name = (link.split('/'))[-2] + ex
img = open(name + '.gif', 'wb').write(r.content)
os.remove(name + '.gif')```
````

Comment: Если у вас pythonanywhere бесплатный, то он запрещает подключаться к кому попало, в том числе к проксям

Comment: @andreymal, не знал, спасибо, не знаете бесплатные хосты на несколько дней?

Comment: Если «на несколько дней», то, может, просто используйте свой собственный домашний компьютер?

Comment: @andreymal не хочется чтобы пк работал 24 на 7 3 дня